# solving for one variable in terms of others

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms

A question from Steward's Precalculus textbook 5th, Pg 55,

the original formula is $$h=\frac{1}{2}gt^2+V_0t$$

the question asks to write the formula in terms of $t$, the answer is $$t=\dfrac{-V_0\pm\sqrt{v_0^2+2gh}}{g}$$

I don't know the steps on how to get there

Comment: HINT: Move $h$ to the RHS and use the Quadratic Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$h=\frac{1}{2}gt^2+V_0t$$
$$2h=gt^2+2V_0t$$
$$gt^2+2V_0t-2h=0$$

now use this formula for Quadratic equation:$ax^2+bx+c=0$;
$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

so: $$t=\dfrac{-2V_0\pm\sqrt{4V_0^2+8gh}}{2g} $$
$$t=\dfrac{-V_0\pm\sqrt{V_0^2+2gh}}{g} $$